# XML with Same Attribute on multiple tags using C++ boost property tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost

Is is possible to produce the following XML using C++ boost::property_tree?

```
<tests>
    <test id="12" age="7">123</test>
    <test id="15" age="8">1rr</test>
    <test id="52" age="71">1qe3</test>
    <test id="72" age="5">1d5</test>
</tests>
```

I used:

```
test.add("<xmlattr>.id", 12);
test.add("<xmlattr>.age", 8);
tests.add_child("test", test);
//Called multiple times
```

And it produced an error:

```
Attribute id Redefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate `test` elements:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7baeddca9e117274)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    struct { int id, age; std::string value; } data[] = {
        { 12, 7, "123" },
        { 15, 8, "1rr" },
        { 52, 71, "1qe3" },
        { 72, 5, "1d5" },
    };

    ptree tests;

    for (auto& item : data) {
        ptree test;
        test.add("<xmlattr>.id", item.id);
        test.add("<xmlattr>.age", item.age);
        test.put_value(item.value);
        tests.add_child("test", test);
    };

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.add_child("tests", tests);
    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
}
```

Prints:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tests>
    <test id="12" age="7">123</test>
    <test id="15" age="8">1rr</test>
    <test id="52" age="71">1qe3</test>
    <test id="72" age="5">1d5</test>
</tests>
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by adding `test.clear()` before adding attributes

Comment: @Ja.L this just shows why you need to supply a SSCCE/MVCE example. Because that kind of thing was impossible to diagnose from the code you showed ;) Could have saved everyone time there. Better yet, frequently, you can answer your own question while making the SSCCE (http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)